# Get the local IP of client on HttpRequestHandler

Tags: java, android, apache

I'm writing an app that needs to communicate with other phones locally. (within the same wifi network) After following [this](http://www.integratingstuff.com/2011/10/24/adding-a-webserver-to-an-android-app/) tutorial have a very simple apache webserver running on port 8202, however I’d like to know the **local** IP of the client making the request.

Webserver class:

```
public class WebServer {

public static boolean RUNNING = false;
public static int serverPort = 8202;
private Context context = null;

private BasicHttpProcessor httpproc = null;
private BasicHttpContext httpContext = null;
private HttpService httpService = null;
private HttpRequestHandlerRegistry registry = null;

public WebServer(Context context) {
    this.setContext(context);

    httpproc = new BasicHttpProcessor();
    httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();

    httpproc.addInterceptor(new ResponseDate());
    httpproc.addInterceptor(new ResponseServer());
    httpproc.addInterceptor(new ResponseContent());
    httpproc.addInterceptor(new ResponseConnControl());

    httpService = new HttpService(httpproc, new DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy(), new DefaultHttpResponseFactory());

    registry = new HttpRequestHandlerRegistry();
    registry.register("*", new CommandHandler(context));

    httpService.setHandlerResolver(registry);
}

private ServerSocket serverSocket;

public void runServer() {
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort);

        serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);

        while (RUNNING) {
            try {
                final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

                DefaultHttpServerConnection serverConnection = new DefaultHttpServerConnection();

                serverConnection.bind(socket, new BasicHttpParams());

                httpService.handleRequest(serverConnection, httpContext);

                serverConnection.shutdown();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (HttpException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        serverSocket.close();
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    RUNNING = false;
}

public synchronized void startServer() {
    RUNNING = true;
    Log.d("SEVRER", "running");
    runServer();
}

public synchronized void stopServer() {
    RUNNING = false;
    if (serverSocket != null) {
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Log.d("SEVRER", "stopping");
}

public void setContext(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public Context getContext() {
    return context;
}
```

CommandHandler class:

```
public class CommandHandler implements HttpRequestHandler {
private Context context = null;

public CommandHandler(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void handle(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, HttpContext httpContext) throws HttpException, IOException {

    HttpEntity entity = new EntityTemplate(new ContentProducer() {
        public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream) throws IOException {
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outstream, "UTF-8");
            writer.write("output");
            writer.flush();
        }
    });
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    response.setEntity(entity);
}

public Context getContext() {
    return context;
}
```

Is there something I’m missing or should I use something else to run a server?

Comment: you could only ever see the IP that the client's request is coming from. If the other device decides to go out onto the cell network instead of the local wifi network, then you'd get the IP of the cell provider's proxy/NAT gateway, not the phone's. If there's a local proxy of some sort, you'd get that proxy's IP.

Comment: That shouldn’t be a problem, the app won't connect but that’s an user error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
```

inside your runServer() method.

Comment: Would that give me my own IP or the IP of the client? (sorry for asking, but it sounds like the first)

Comment: That would give you the client's IP. I've corrected my answer.